# java.net.URI chokes on special characters in host part

Tags: java, http, url-encoding

I have a URI string like the following:

> http://www.christlichepartei%F6sterreichs.at/steiermark/

I'm creating a java.lang.URI instance with this string and it succeeds but when I want to retrieve the host it returns null. Opera and Firefox also choke on this URL if I enter it exactly as shown above. But shouldn't the URI class throw a URISyntaxException if it is invalid? How can I detect that the URI is illegal then?

It also behaves the same when I decode the string using URLDecoder which yields

> http://www.christlicheparteiösterreichs.at/steiermark/

Now this is accepted by Opera and Firefox but java.net.URI still doesn't like it. How can I deal with such a URL?

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Java 6 has [`IDN`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/IDN.html) class to work with internationalized domain names. So, the following produces URI with encoded hostname:

```
URI u = new URI("http://" + IDN.toASCII("www.christlicheparteiösterreichs.at") + "/steiermark/");
```

Comment: `IDN#toASCII` is intended only to work on labels or full domain names, not entire URI strings.  This may cause unintended consequences.

Answer (score 2):

The correct way to encode non-ASCII characters in hostnames is known as ["Punycode"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Punycode).

Answer (score 2):

[URI](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URI.html#URI%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) throws an [URISyntaxException](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URISyntaxException.html), when you choose the appropriate constructor:

```
URI someUri=new URI("http","www.christlicheparteiösterreichs.at","/steiermark",null);
```

> java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in hostname at index 28: http://www.christlicheparteiösterreichs.at/steiermark

You can use [IDN](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/IDN.html) for this to fix:

```
URI someUri=new URI("http",IDN.toASCII("www.christlicheparteiösterreichs.at"),"/steiermark",null);
System.out.println(someUri);
System.out.println("host: "+someUri.getHost()));
```

Output:

> http://www.xn--christlicheparteisterreichs-5yc.at/steiermark
>
> host: www.xn--christlicheparteisterreichs-5yc.at

**UPDATE** regarding the chicken-egg-problem:

You can let URL do the job:

```
public static URI createSafeURI(final URL someURL) throws URISyntaxException
{
return new URI(someURL.getProtocol(),someURL.getUserInfo(),IDN.toASCII(someURL.getHost()),someURL.getPort(),someURL.getPath(),someURL.getQuery(),someURL.getRef());    
}


URI raoul=createSafeURI(new URL("http://www.christlicheparteiösterreichs.at/steiermark/readme.html#important"));
```

This is just a quick-shot, it is not checked all issues concerning converting an URL to an URI. Use it as a starting point.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your answer but how does the URI constructor help me when I don't have the individual parts of the URL. It's a bit of a chicken and egg problem :)

Comment: You are right. It depends from where do you get your data. If you get an String like "http://www.christlicheparteiösterreichs.at/steiermark/" as input, you just cannot use it in new URI(String), because the JavaDoc states, it wants an already correct URI-String. But this string is not. You have to check where in the dataflow the String gets "corrupted". Where does this string come from?

Comment: Hi, thanks for taking the time to look into this. THe suggestion in your update looks promising, I probably can work with that. Thanks again!