# Handling special characters in domain names (without IDN)?

Tags: java, android, url, utf-8, idn

I am using the URI class to break apart a string url.

The getHost() method returns null when there are special characters in it.

Such as:  [http://✪df.ws/g44](http://%E2%9C%AAdf.ws/g44)

[It was suggested to use the IDN class to work around this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3803490/java-net-uri-chokes-on-special-characters-in-host-part).  However, that class is only available in the Android API level 9 and above, which means 2.3 and above.

Is there another way to do this without the IDN class?

I want to be able to break apart a string url into the various pieces and be able to handle modern urls.

Thanks

**Update** It looks like the WebView doesn't support these types of urls either. So, it looks like I need to find a way to support or convert these urls for pre 2.3 devices.

Is there a way to convert these urls without the IDN class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

getHost() = ignore everything from the start until :// and then capture everything until you get a slash.

Wouldn't that work?

Comment: I guess that would work, I was trying to use the URI methods since I figured they would be the safest, but I imagine this should work for the host at least.

Comment: @littleFluffyKitty: You can make it work with other segments by applying the same logic to the following tokens: `://`, `:`, `@`, `/`, `?`, `&`, `#`.

Comment: Thanks, that would do it.  However, I updated my question (it didn't seem different enough to warrant a separate question), since it does look like I need a way to support/convert these characters.